# sed/awk replace word in specific position of sentence

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, awk

I'm trying to replace a word at a specific position of a line

For example, given:

```
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (1,'Monrovia');
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (2,'Brunswick');
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (3,'Phenix City');
```

I want to replace all different the cities with 'Detroit', resulting in:

```
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (1,'Detroit');
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (2,'Detroit');
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (3,'Detroit');
```

Please, How can i do that in sed, awk, or vim?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest: Keep the script, append

```
UPDATE address SET city ='Detroit'
```

In vim:

```
:g/^INSERT INTO address/normal f;F'ci'Detroit
```

In sed:

```
sed "s/\(VALUES (.*,\)'.*\?'/\1'Detroit'/g"
```

Answer (score 3):

Huh? That's easy:

```
$ echo "INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (1,'Monrovia');
> INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (2,'Brunswick'); 
> INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (3,'Phenix City');" | 
> sed "s/'[^']*'/'Detroit'/g"
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (1,'Detroit'); 
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (2,'Detroit'); 
INSERT INTO address (city_id,city) VALUES (3,'Detroit');
```

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: I was guessing the _'specific point in sentence'_ was in fact supplied for a reason (even though the sample doesn't show that reason)

Comment: I chose to believe that the poster is obviously not a native English speaker, and therefore had no idea what he was actually saying... so I took the simplest (most common) interpretation of: He's just clueless about regexes.

Comment: @user380690: So is the problem solved? If so mark this response as correct. This tell other users not to bothering answering, and also tells anybody who finds this post in future (those with a similar problem, who know how to use google) that this positted solution was in fact a solution.